# Websocket client with Flack - It is possible to use Fleck as a client?

Tags: c#, websocket, client

I found the [github example](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) using Flack lib as a server. I would like to use Flack to send stuff to websocket. I found WebSocketConnection class inside Flack lib. But it´s very confusing object with "dozens" of parameters that I don´t have idea how to get them.

There is a way to use Fleck as a websocket client? I mean, using something like a WebSocketClient(that doesn´t exists in the lib) ? There is another way?

Thanks!